# content in XML cdata section is showing without cdata tag in mozilla

Tags: c#, xml, rss

The contents of an RSS 2.0 XML 's CDATA section is showing without the `CDATA` keyword in Mozilla. But is shows properly in chrome.

In chrome

```
<description:encoded>
    <![CDATA[ test ]]>
</description:encoded>
```

In firefox

```
<description:encoded>test</description:encoded>
```

Comment: I think we lack information before we can help you. What are you trying to do? Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of some code?

Comment: `<![CDATA[  ]]>` this tag is not showing but the content inside it is showing  when opening the rss feed xml in mozilla firefox